# What is the difference/purpose of 'content' and 'elements' keys, in preprocess?

Tags: theming, hooks, 9

I'm using `hook_preprocess_node` and looking at `$variables`. I can see there's two similar keys: `content` and `elements`. I see that there's a [comment in the core code](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/):

```
  // Helpful $content variable for templates.
```

next to code that copies all `elements` keys into `content`... I'm unsure *why* it's helpful, *how* it's different, and *when* one would use `elements` or `content` to achieve a particular goal.

This is a general question, but my task at hand is that I have two separate taxonomy term reference fields and I wish to combine them, alphabetically by term name, into one list for presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elements` is the variable name defined in [theme_hook()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme) to hold the renderable elements (for the node this is the entity build array). Preprocess is then responsible to prepare variables for rendering, like `content`.

If your goal is to modify the template output then check first which variables are actually printed. In a node template it doesn't make sense to change `elements` in preprocess, any changes you make will be discarded. You can however do this in the build process, for example in [hook_entity_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter).

Comment: So the *node* module generates a render array with all the node's data in render arrays under `'elements'`. Then `template_preprocess_node()` sets defaults for the node, which is where the whole *copy `elements` to `content`* comes from. So this means `elements` is only left there "just in case" (?) but that in terms of continuing the render process, `content` is what now matters. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, but in your case you might want to change the build array before it reaches the preprocess hook. This looks more like you want to alter the build array, not to theme the output.

Comment: Thanks, I've started [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309299/render-two-taxonomy-fields-in-one-alphabetical-list/309300#309300) for that part of the task, to keep things clearer.