# Render two taxonomy fields in one alphabetical list

Tags: theming, 9

I have two term reference fields: colours and tags.

I have a poppy, it has tags: *pretty* and colours: *red*, *green*.

I want html like:

> This flower is: green, pretty, red

i.e.

- I want to take the terms from two fields and merge them into one collection.

### I tried in Twig:

I started in twig. I could combine the terms but I couldn't sort them.

```
{% set alltags = content.field_tags['items']|merge(content.field_colours['items']|keys|map(i => content.field_colours[i])) %} 
{{ alltags }}
```

### I tried in pre process

I then moved to PHP in a `mytheme_preprocess_node()` function. I thought I could sneak a few of the *colours* terms in under the *tags* field... It seemed to add them to the object OK, but none of the colour ones were output.

```
/** @var Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList */
$coloursTags = $variables['content']['field_colours']['#items'] ?? NULL;
if ($coloursTags && $coloursTags->count()) {
  $tags = $variables['content']['field_tags']['#items'];
  foreach ($coloursTags as $item) {
    /** @var Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem $item */
    $tags->appendItem($item->getValue());
  }
}
```

I have since found a couple of ways that work, which I'll post in an answer so as to attract better answers than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of ways to achieve it, posting here, but I'm open to better/cleaner ways. I'm especially unhappy in my answers with the way to access the tag name - seems so overly complicated trying to get the raw name?!

Both code blocks live in a `mytheme_preprocess_node()`:

### Answer 1: create a new variable with all the tags in it:

```php
<?php

  $allTags = [];
  $addTags = function($fieldName) use (&$allTags, $variables) {
    if (isset($variables['content'][$fieldName])) {
      foreach (\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($variables['content'][$fieldName]) as $i) {
        $allTags[]= $variables['content'][$fieldName][$i];
      }
    }
  };
  $addTags('field_colours');
  $addTags('field_tags');
  usort($allTags, function ($a, $b) {
    $tagA = $a['#taxonomy_term']->name->getValue()[0]['value'];
    $tagB = $b['#taxonomy_term']->name->getValue()[0]['value'];
    return strcasecmp($tagA, $tagB);
  });
  $variables['content']['allTags'] = $allTags;
```

Then in Twig for the node template: `{{ allTags }}`.

### Answer 2: mix the tags from the colour field into the tags field in the render array

```php
<?php

  $allTagsTemp = [];
  foreach (\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($variables['content']['field_tags']) as $i) {
    $tag = $variables['content']['field_tags'][$i];
    unset($tag['#weight']);
    unset($variables['content']['field_tags'][$i]);
    $allTagsTemp[] = $tag;
  }
  foreach (\Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children($variables['content']['field_colours']) as $i) {
    $tag = $variables['content']['field_colours'][$i];
    unset($tag['#weight']);
    unset($variables['content']['field_colours'][$i]);
    $allTagsTemp[] = $tag;
  }
  usort($allTagsTemp, function ($a, $b) {
    $tagA = $a['#taxonomy_term']->name->getValue()[0]['value'];
    $tagB = $b['#taxonomy_term']->name->getValue()[0]['value'];
    return strcasecmp($tagA, $tagB);
  });
  $variables['content']['field_tags'] += $allTagsTemp;
```

Then in Twig `{{ field_tags }}`.

Comment: `$a['#taxonomy_term']->name->getValue()[0]['value']` can be shortened to `$a['#taxonomy_term']->label()`

Comment: @Clive thank you, I thought there must be a short cut!!